# How to automatically delete blank row/cells when export to other worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a few raw data files which some row/cell does not have data. How do I automatically delete those empty row/cells when I move/export the data to other work sheet. what formula should I use to do so?

I've attached picture below. for clearer explanation.

[image: Picture example]

Comment: I'd recommend to sort source data before copy/move. All empty rows will move down, and you can do not copy them.

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to suggest you a Macro (VBA code), will help you to Delete all empty rows form the used range, and then after you can Export the sheet.*

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()

  Dim lastRow As Long
  LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + _
      ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  For r = LastRow To 1 Step -1
  If Application.CountA(Rows(r)) = 0 Then    
    Rows(r).Delete
  End if

Next r

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Press `Alt+F11` to open VB editor.
- Copy & Paste this code as standard module.
- Finally RUN this Macro.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished easily if you select only the cells with data, then do a copy/paste:

1. Highlight the whole range (A2:A13),
2. Press F5 (Goto),
3. Click Special...,
4. Select "Constants", then OK
5. Ctrl-C to copy
6. Paste into new location (B2)

If these are formulas rather than constants, you can pick "Formulas" in step 4.

Comment: A similar approach would be to turn on filtering and hide blanks, then copy and paste.